# Downloading Multiple Files; ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having issues with downloading files in ASP.NET MVC using Visual Studio. The main purpose of my code is to store licensing files in my local file system. My upload function is working fine, however, my download function is not. Because the database I am using is unable to store lists, I currently store each file name in a string as such: "9-0.lic,9-1.lic,9-2.lic,". The first number (9) is the primary key for my SoftwareLicense Model, and the number after the dash is the license file number (1, 2 and 3).

SoftwareLicense Model:

```
public class SoftwareLicense
{
    [Key]
    public int SoftwareID { get; set; } // Properties of class SoftwareLicense

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual IntranetUser User { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Software title field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Software Title")]
    public string SoftwareName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The software key field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Software Key")]
    public string SoftwareKey { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The software price field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Software Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "License File")]
    public string LicenseFileName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "File Path")]
    public string LicenseFilePath { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The start date field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The end date field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The license type field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "License Type")]
    public string LicenseType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Department Name")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The notify time field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Notify Time")]
    public int NotifyTime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Entry Created By")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

PreDownload Method in SoftwareLicense Controller:

```
public ActionResult PreDownload(int ID)
    {
        SoftwareLicense softwareLicense = db.SoftwareLicenses.Find(ID);

        var fileNames = softwareLicense.LicenseFileName.Split(',');

        foreach(string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            if(fileName.Length > 1)
            {
                Download(fileName, softwareLicense.SoftwareName);
            }
        }
        SetUserInfo();
        return View("Details", softwareLicense);
    }
```

Download Method in SoftwareLicense Controller:

```
public FileResult Download(string fileName, string licenseName)
    {
        string returnName = licenseName + '-' + fileName;

        if((fileName != "") || (fileName != " "))
        {
            return File("C:/Users/heathera/Desktop/Licenses/" + fileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, returnName);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

If anyone has any pointers or solutions please let me know, I have been stuck on this for a day or two now and can't seem to figure it out. Also, if you have any pointers on any of my code I am always willing to learn about smarter programming.

Thanks in advance!
Andrew.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: If you want to return multiple files you would be best off putting them in a container eg a zip file

Comment: @stuartd - No files are downloading.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow

Comment: @stuartd - Also, I have tried to put the files in a zip but my implementation of that was also unsuccessful

Comment: You're at no point returning the `FileResult`

Comment: You need to change your code to this: `return Download(...);`

Comment: @jumpingcode - Can you please elaborate? Possibly provide some examples?

Comment: @DavidG Has touched on it. But furthermore, this will only return one result rather than multiple file downloads, you should return them in a zip

Comment: I would implement returning a zip containing all of the files, but my mentor thinks it would be best to return each file individually.

Comment: To return each fine individually, it's easiest to present the user with a list of links to click on. You can make some browsers download more than one file, but it's awkward and the user will likely be presented with a warning.

Comment: @DavidG - Thanks for the pointer David. I will attempt an implementation and report back shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that my issues were caused due to a browser issue. After reading @DavidG's response, I was able to successfully alter my PreDownload action of the SoftwareLicense Controller to create a List of file names that need to be downloaded. From there, I created a new view named "DownloadList" and created an HTML table with the file names being the first column, and an ActionLink passing the file name to the Download action in the SoftwareLicense Controller being the second column.

This approach appears to be working perfectly, plus I didn't have to change my Download action drastically (had to alter a few lines to define file name and license name though)!

Thank you @DavidG!

***** Updated Code Below *****

SoftwareLicense Model did not change.

PreDownload Action in SoftwareLicense Controller:

```
public ActionResult PreDownload(int ID)
    {

        SoftwareLicense softwareLicense = db.SoftwareLicenses.Find(ID);

        TempData["SoftwareID"] = softwareLicense.SoftwareID;

        var fileNames = softwareLicense.LicenseFileName.Split(',');

        List<string> downloadList = new List<string>();

        foreach(string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            if(fileName.Length > 1)
            {
                downloadList.Add(softwareLicense.SoftwareName + '_' + fileName);
            }
        }
        SetUserInfo();
        return View("DownloadList", downloadList);
    }
```

Download Action in SoftwareLicense Controller:

```
public FileResult Download(string fileName)
    {
        string licenseName = fileName.Split('_')[1];

        string filePath = "C:/Users/heathera/Desktop/Licenses/" + licenseName;

        string returnName = fileName;

        if((fileName != "") || (fileName != " "))
        {
            return File(filePath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, returnName);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```